# VisualVm : cpu graph pannel show "Not supported for this JVM"

Tags: spring-boot, monitoring, cpu-usage, visualvm

I'm going to debug springBoot application using visualvm. In local environment I could monitor,

1. heap
2. class
3. cpu
4. thread

But when I trying to monitor application instance running in remote server All grapg pannels works except cpu graph. cpu graph pannel show "Not supported for this JVM".

I have started jstatd deamon in remote server using following command

```
jstatd -p 1099 -J-Djava.security.policy=<(echo 'grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {permission java.security.AllPermission;};')
```

Any help to enable cpu matrics is highly appreciate

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in my answer I have run jstatd deamon to collection and expose metrics.I couldn't recover cpu graph with this approach. Finally I decided to take another approach with jmx,

1. Run the application.jar with following command

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=15000  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=15001  -jar application.jar
```

2. Add jmx connection to remote visualVm
   [image: jmx configuring window]

then I could get all the metrics

Comment: Great ! @Damitha !